# How to define constants that can be used across config files in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

As I checked on multiple sources, the Laravel way of defining constant variables is through config files. However, in my case, I want to use constants across my config files which is not possible since, as I read, it's not possible/advisable to call a config from another.

## EXAMPLE

Constants:

```
define('THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE', 1);
define('THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_UGLY', 2);
define('THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_BAD', 12372);
```

config1.php

```
return [
   THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE = ['many', 'nice', 'data'],
]
```

config2.php

```
return [
   ['many', 'nice', 'data', THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE],
]
```

As you can see, I just can't use the actual value of the defined constants since it'll be too unreadable. Also I don't want to clump up my .env file with these constants since it's not really meant for it.

Any workaround for this? Thanks.

P.S
Why does this so hard whilst it should be very basic principle of PHP to utilise constant definitions. CI has these figured out :/

Comment: I think you can use `include` ? And you can control it where you want use it.

Comment: Define such constant in .env file then

Comment: @lighter seems to be the only way. I never thought I would go vanilla PHP on this, still hoping for a more Laravel way :) thanks tho

Comment: @ACD, I post my answer. If you have any idea, I hope you can share with me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use php `include` on your `config.php` if you don't want add a lot of to `.env` file. Just like that

```
<?php

include 'something_constant.php';

return [
   THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE = ['many', 'nice', 'data'],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to add them to the `config/app.php` file. Somewhere above the providers[] list you could add

```
'CONST' => ['THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE' => 1,
            'THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_UGLY' => 2, 
           ],
```

and **anywhere** in the code access the values with the laravel helper `config('app.CONST.THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE');`

You can make use of the `.env` file but beware that in production, this file is ignored because the config is automatically cached. In .env you could add the line `THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE=1` and in the `config/app.php` file you add

```
'CONST' => ['THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE' => env('THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE'),],
```

from where you can access the value just the same with the `config()` helper.

Personally I add the values in the `app.php` file and don't bother with adding values to .env, because mostly these contain non-critical information (i.e. your private keys etc)

If you'd like to create a separate file to isolate from the other config files, you could create a file f.ex. `config/constants.php` and return an array as it is done in other config files. Make it a flat array (no `'CONST'` key). In the `app/providers/AppServiceProvider` in the `register()` method add

```
$this->mergeConfigFrom('config/constants.php', 'constants');
```

This way you can access your constants with `config('constants.THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE');`

Comment: the thing is, I have tons of these defined variables. like 500+ of them, I don't want to bloat out any core files of laravel. i want them somewhere else isolated.

Comment: I'll add another possibility to my answer that may satisfy your request.

Comment: In the follow up you could opt to group your constants as they are so many in `'user' => [...], 'admin' => [...], 'public' => [...],` etc. Accessing a value would be `config('constants.public.THE_ID_OF_SOMETHING_NICE');`